# Exclusive left join on multiple table

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm building a query in which I try to make an exclusive left join but I couldn't find a solution without using two queries put together with union all.

My SQL that doesn't work as expected :

```
select link_table.key as lk_key, table_a.key as a_key, table_b.key as b_key
from link_table
left join table_a on (link_table.key = table_a.key_link_table)
left join table_b on (link_table.key = table_b.key_link_table)
```

What I get as result :

```
lk_key     a_key   b_key
123        abc     xyz
456        def     uvw
789        ghi     NULL
```

My workaround :

```
select link_table.key as lk_key, table_a.key as a_key, null as b_key from link_table
left join table_a on (link_table.key = table_a.key_link_table)
union all
select link_table.key as lk_key, null as a_key, table_b.key as b_key from link_table
left join table_b on (link_table.key = table_b.key_link_table)
```

What I get as a result  and would like the first SQL to perform :

```
lk_key     a_key   b_key
123        abc     NULL
123        NULL    xyz
456        def     NULL
456        NULL    uvw
789        ghi     NULL
```

Is this possible in one query?

Comment: What's wrong with your "workaround"?

Comment: If it works, why change it?  Is it taking 9 years to run?  Does it pull the wrong data?  Does it have too many vowels in it?

Comment: I thought maybe there was a sql/oracle keyword that fits my specific need instead of using union. And no I don't have performance issues for now. It's just it took me some time until I figured out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Reformatted Question: Please use code to put this stuff in here.

```
select 
link_table.key as lk_key,
table_a.key as a_key,
table_b.key as b_key 
    from link_table 
left join table_a on 
    (link_table.key = table_a.key_link_table) 
left join table_b on 
    (link_table.key = table_b.key_link_table)
```

What I get as result :

```
lk_key a_key b_key 
123 abc xyz 
456 def uvw 
789 ghi NULL
```

Wanted result:

```
lk_key a_key b_key
123 abc NULL 
123 NULL xyz 
456 def NULL 
456 NULL uvw  
789 ghi NULL
```

My workaround

```
select * from link_table 
left join 
table_a on (link_table.key = table_a.key_link_table) 

union all 

select * 
from link_table 
left join table_b on 
  (link_table.key = table_b.key_link_table)
```

Try this:

```
select 
link_table.key as lk_key,
table_a.key as a_key,
table_b.key as b_key 
    from link_table 
full outer join table_a on 
    (link_table.key = table_a.key_link_table) 
full outer join table_b on 
    (link_table.key = table_b.key_link_table)
where a_key is NULL or
b_key is NULL
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qje6o.png

Comment: Thank you, I'll try with full outer joins see if it works as soon as I get access to the DB again.